# How can I render multiple draw modes?

Tags: qt, opengl

I've created a program that switches draw modes (GL_TRIANGLES, GL_POINTS, GL_LINE_LOOP, etc). I render these draw modes using glDrawArarys(), but every time I switch to a new draw mode it sets all my previous points I created in the previous draw mode to the new draw mode.

I want to disconnect these points so I can have shapes of 2 different draw modes in the same render. How can I do this?

Below is the problem. My GL_TRIANGLE points become GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP points after switching to a new draw mode.

[image: This is the problem]

Comment: You might want to post a short section of your rendering code so we can see what you are currently doing to help identify what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw twice. The first one with a `GL_TRIANGLES` primitive and the second one with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` primitive. Something like this:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, first, count);

// do any atualization in Uniforms, if necessary to update transformations
// and do it again
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first, count);
```

Comment: That does work for short term, but what happens when I want to go back to drawing GL_TRIANGLES? Would I have to keep a separate int array containing the indices of where each draw mode starts?

Comment: @tim: OpenGL is not a scene graph. You tell it to draw something, something is drawn and that's it. OpenGL does not keep a scene around. Whatever you want to see, you have to tell it OpenGL in verbatim. There's no such thing as "adding to a scene" or "updating". You always draw the whole frame from the beginning.

Comment: @datenwolf: So there is no draw function that can just update the scene or separate the points without having to specify where the draw modes end?

Comment: @tim: It's really hard to tell without seeing the code you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can always abstract this issue to your set of shapes.

If each of your shapes that you are drawing is a single object you can easily do this. You can create a shape class which stores a set of points and sets up your VBO, this class can then contain a `render()` method.

You shape class can store a `GLenum drawMode` which  is then a handle to the draw mode for that shape. Then instead of writing all the draw code and duplicating it in your `glRenderLoop()` you can write it in the `render()` method and just call the render method of your shape in the `glRenderLoop()`.

The `render()` method will then use the applicable draw mode depending on how you created the shape.